# Javascript used to be a lisp?

Tags: javascript, syntax, lisp

One of our senior devs was telling me today that javascript actually started out as a lisp (complete with s-expressions), I am wondering if that is factual and if so, could I get a reference to where this is stated?

Comment: THIS IS NOT A DUPLICATE. Question says nothing about javascript and s-expressions explicitly.

Comment: javascript is an ecmascript.

Comment: I'm not asking if javascript IS a lisp. I'm asking if it WAS a lisp. it's right in the title people

Comment: I googled "history of Javascript", but none of the pages I checked have any details about the original syntax.

Comment: @Barmar Im sceptical of his assertion, that's why I'm asking here. Hopefully someone might have some inside info on the history. Or maybe what he heard is apocryphal.

Comment: Something like this is probably better asked somewhere more specific: https://esdiscuss.org/ . Or mail Brendan Eich directly, he will probably answer you.

Comment: This part of one of Crockford's lectures may also be relevant https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JxAXlJEmNMg#t=1h36m54s

Comment: @PaulS. Nice link, thanks

Comment: @TylerGillies "Chapter 2" goes into it in a bit more detail than the really brief bit at the end of "Chapter 1", if you don't mind watching a lecture